# How to search for a range of values using binary search?

Tags: java, range, binary-search

I am trying to write a program that will take an *ArrayList* of sorted integers, and there will be a binary search method where you specify the range and the values that you want to be returned from the *ArrayList*.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArraySearch {
    ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> range = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static ArrayList<Integer> binarySearch(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList, int min, int max, int first, int last)
                                        throws NotFoundException {
    if(first > last) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Elements not found.");
    }
    else {
        int middle = (first + last) /2;
        int mid_number = arrayList.get(middle);

        if(mid_number >= min && mid_number <= max)
        {
            range.add(middle);
        }

        if(mid_number <= min) {
            if(mid_number == min) {
                range.add(arrayList.get(middle));
                return binarySearch(arrayList, min, max, first, middle-1);
            }
            return binarySearch(arrayList, min, max, first, middle-1);
        }
        else {
            if(mid_number == max) {
                range.add(arrayList.get(middle));
                return binarySearch(arrayList, min, max, middle+1,last);
            }
            return binarySearch(arrayList, min, max, middle+1,last);
        }
    }   
}

public static void main (String [] args) throws NotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(0);       
                a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(6);
    a.add(7);
    a.add(7);
    a.add(10);
    a.add(10);
    a.add(10);

    binarySearch(a, 3, 7, 0, 9);
}
```

}

Could I please get some help?
I have no idea what the base case condition should be that should return the *ArrayList* range. And I think I might have got the logic in the binary search method wrong.

Comment: You can binary search the minimum value of the range and then maximum and return everything in between.

Comment: You might as well just find the minimum and then iterate linearly up from there until you go over the maximum. It will take linear time to build up the return value anyway.

Comment: Bula could you elaborate more on how to do this because I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

First , find the lower index range of the element. then , find the upper index range of the element .
To find lower index range, when you find the element, instead of breaking out of the loop, like we do so in normal search. put the value in index and make the mid one less than the current index you are checking. This will make the loop go again to find the lower index and not stop at the first index.
Similarly for the upper index , update start to the current index we are checking + 1.
Have a look at the code.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> searchRange(ArrayList<Integer> a, int b) {
    int first=lowerIndex(a,b);
    int last=upperIndex(a,b);
    ArrayList<Integer> result= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    result.add(first);
    result.add(last);
    return result;

}

public int upperIndex(ArrayList<Integer> a, int b) {
    int index=-1; //will return -1 if element not found.
    int start=0;
    int end=a.size()-1;

    while(start<=end){
        int mid=(start+end)/2;
        if(a.get(mid)==b){
            index=mid;    //Update Index, which is the upper index here.
            start=mid+1; // This is the main step.
        }
        else if(a.get(mid)>b){
            end=mid-1;
        }
        else{
            start=mid+1;
        }
    }


    return index;
}

public int lowerIndex(ArrayList<Integer> a, int b) {
    int index=-1; // will return -1 if element not found
    int start=0;
    int end=a.size()-1;

    while(start<=end){
        int mid=(start+end)/2;
        if(a.get(mid)==b){
            index=mid;  //Update Index, which is the lower index here.
            end=mid-1; // This is the main step .
        }
        else if(a.get(mid)>b){
            end=mid-1;
        }
        else{
            start=mid+1;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```